# Button and textviews not being shown on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two linear layouts within a relative layout. The spinner in the code is showing, but neither of the textviews nor the button are shown in the emulator. I've tried messing around with different layout attributes with no success thus far. Can someone help me?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.gymtracker.WorkoutActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Reps"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:hint="Weight"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
    android:onClick="newReps"
    android:text="+" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tried your xml, everything shows up. Are you sure that you are using the same xml?

Comment: your activity code? might be the setContentView

Comment: Turns out the problem was in my activity code, I was missing some code and didn't think to look in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gymtracker.WorkoutActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        android:onClick="newReps"
        android:text="+" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:hint="Weight"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Reps"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```